# JasperReports exception loading jrxml file

Tags: exception, hadoop, jasper-reports, hive

When I call in my code:

```java
JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(reportTemplate);
```

it print to console an error and then throws me an exception:

```
ERROR extensions.DefaultExtensionsRegistry: Error instantiating extensions registry for queryexecuters.hive from jar:file:/C:/Users/GDantimi/workspace/ProvaJasper/lib/js-hive-datasource-1.1.jar!/jasperreports_extension.properties

net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: Could not load class com.jaspersoft.hadoop.hive.HiveQueryExecuterExtensionsRegistryFactory
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.ClassUtils.instantiateClass(ClassUtils.java:63)
```

I searched for that library but I haven't found anything.

Comment: I know nothing about hadoop, but does `C:/Users/GDantimi/workspace/ProvaJasper/lib/js-hive-datasource-1.1.jar` exist in that location. I would start there.

Comment: @jschoen Ok found it. Thanks.

Comment: @jschoen I still get an error:
--[ERROR] Error instantiating extensions registry for queryexecuters.hive from jar:file:/C:/Users/GDantimi/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp3/wtpwebapps/SirsapASD/WEB-INF/lib/js-hive-datasource-1.1.jar!/jasperreports_extension.properties
--net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: Could not load